# Want to change Feature Product Image Size in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

Hi i want to Create custom Featured Product in Magento 2. Below code use to get Product images:

```
$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
if ($pos != null) {
    $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
        . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
}

echo $productImage->toHtml();
```

Currently Getting Image size as per Define in **`etc/view.xml`** in Theme, But i want to change Custom Image size for feature product in Homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your **PHTML** file you need to set **$image = 'homepage_page_grid';** tag as I show here.

then use this **$image** tag in product Image like below.

```
$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
```

now go to **vendor_name/theme/name/etc/view.xml** file and add your image with id that you set in PHTML file.

```
<image id="homepage_page_grid" type="thumbnail">
            <width>200</width>
            <height>200</height>
        </image>
```

Hope this will help you.